# Does it matter which file is created first for makefile?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I'm so confused 
so say I have the following

```
all: one

one: two

two: three

three: 

   echo Hello
```

Then 
creating the file "all" more recently than the file "one" or creating the file "three" more recently than the file "one" change the out put hello??

Comment: `all` is only "special" because it is the first, or `default`, rule.

Comment: You can't remove `one` and `two` because then `all` won't have a rule for its dependency, `one`.

Comment: @FiddlingBits yes but removing them won't do harm for echoing hello

Comment: Read [GNU `make` documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html). Consider using [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) (as `remake -x`) to debug your `Makefile`

Answer (score 1):

`all`, `one`, `two` and `three` are not **files**. They are **targets**.

None of your rules create any files corresponding to these targets. Make will treat the targets as files, because they are not declared **phony**.

The first target in the file is `all`, so it is the default one. Because it is not a `.PHONY` target, Make will access the filesystem to see whether there exists a file called `all` corresponding to the target. It will notice that `all` does not exist. Therefore the body of the `all` rule (the "recipe") must be executed to create `all`. However, this cannot be done immediately.

The empty recipe of `all` cannot be executed immediately because `all` has a **prerequisite** called `one`. Make will access the filesystem to see whether `one` exists, and see that it doesn't. In this situation, Make searches the rest of the rules to see whether `one` appears as a target, and it does. So then it processes the `one : two` rule to try to update the `one` target.

In this manner, it goes through all the dependent rules until the `three:` rule is reached.  This has no prerequisites, and a file called `three` doesn't exist, so the recipe is executed. The `echo` command is run.

After the `echo` command is run, the recipe terminates with a successful status. At that point, Make assumes that the target `three` has been updated, ignoring the the situation that the file still doesn't exist. Remember, a target is not the same thing as a file; it's a concept in Make and an object in Make's memory. The state of "target has been updated" means only that Make internally marked its in-memory target object as updated, as a result of a recipe having indicated that successfully executed.

Since the `three` target is considered updated, and it is the only prerequisite of `two`, the `two` rule can now be activated. Its empty body is executed, and succeeds, therefore `two` is considered updated.

Similarly, the empty body of the `one :` rule is then executed, and finally of the `all` rule.

What is a phony target? We declare them like this:

```
.PHONY: all one two three
```

this tells Make that all these targets do not correspond to files. A phony target is always treated as if it were a target whose corresponding file is missing, and therefore always requires updating. Make does not check whether a file exists for a phony target.

It's fairly important to declare phony targets. For instance, consider the rule:

```
clean:
        rm -f $(OBJS)
```

If `clean` is not declared `.PHONY:`, then if you accidentally create a file called `clean`, `make clean` will do nothing! Instead, you will see a message like `"make: 'clean' is up to date."`.

Comment: Note that the OP's rules for targets other than `three` do not have *empty* recipes, they have *no* recipes.  This makes them order-only rules, and that's significant because `make` will look for applicable built-in rules to build those targets.  For example, if the working directory contains a file named `one.c`, then `make` would attempt to build a file named `one` by applying its built-in rule for building executables from C sources.

Comment: @JohnBollinger That's a good point; empty rules are not assertions that "this is empty" but "find something default to do" via some pattern.

Answer (score 0):

In order to answer your question, I'm going to have to distinguish between *files* and *recipes* in Make. First, I'll answer your question specifically about this particular makefile, because mathematically speaking there are some really interesting algebraic properties that make this question non-trivial, from an academic standpoint. Feel free to skip the theoretical math section that follows if you really just want an explanation of the practical mechanisms involved, but I do encourage you to explore the mathematical implications of what the example you posted, because the abstract algebra and general mathematics concepts that underlie it are the basis for functional programming, amongst other (many other) things.

---

## Your Question, Literally

If you picture your makefile as a directed graph, where each node is a dependency, you end up with a linear directed graph:

```
all: one

one: two

two: three

three:
    echo "Hello, world!"
```

Becomes:

```
all->one->two->three
```

What this means in practical terms for your specific example is that it's meaningless to think in terms of dependencies, because for all intents and purposes, calling `three` then calling `one` will result in `"Hello, world!"` being printed twice.

The recipe `three` always does the same thing: it returns the string "Hello, world!". (IO is a side-effect, but for the purposes of brevity we're going to pretend that rather than  printing the function the recipe simply returns the string, which for all intents and purposes in this case represent generally the same thing.)

If we think of these recipes as functions in `c` where `main` represents calling `all`, we have the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* Three() {
    return ("Hello, world!");
}

char* Two() {
    return Three();
}

char* One() {
    return Two();
}


int main()
{
    printf("%s\n", One());

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output:

```
Hello, world!
```

Just like in your makefile, this program calls `main`, which calls `One`, which calls `Two`, which calls `Three`, which returns `Hello, world!`. If we now call `Three` and then call `One`, we have, like we said:

```
int main()
{
    printf("%s\n", Three());
    printf("%s\n", One());

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output:

```
Hello, world!
Hello, world!
```

This is because your example is a special case where calling any of the functions `One`, `Two`, or `Three` is equivalent to simply returning a string, meaning that they're pure functions (ignoring the IO, like we said).

If we then consider that you can define a binary operation for concatenating the results of the functions:

```
One()·Two() => "Hello, world!"+"Hello, world!"
```

we can then take this a step further and realize that this operation is associative because `One()·Two() => "Hello, world!"+"Hello, world!"` and `Two()·One() => "Hello, world!"+"Hello, world!"`.

With a binary operation for associative composition established, we can confirm this forms a [Semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup).

This abstract algebraic analysis of types and their compositions is the foundation for things like Category Theory, Type Theory, Haskell, etc.

So let's wrap up this theoretical analysis of your makefile by concretely answering your question: will calling the recipe `three` before calling the recipe `one` affect the printing of `Hello, world!`?

No; having defined our semigroup above, it's clear that from the associative property of its composition, the order in which we call the recipes *in this case* is inconsequential, resulting in structurally identical results.

---

## Practical Stuff

Make uses timestamps to decided whether to trigger a rebuild for a particular recipe. As we mentioned, your build chain is a literal chain, so let's consider the following:

```
all: untitled

untitled: untitled.o

untitled.o: untitled.c
```

In this scenario, you would only be making edits to the source file, as opposed to using a hex editor to manipulate the object file. Once the binary is built, you have `all`, so that's self-explanatory.

It's important to note, however, that in the context of make, these aren't "functions". You're not really supposed to call these recipes explicitly. Otherwise, what's the point of using a build system? So you wouldn't really call `untitled` before calling `untitled.o`, but the second you make changes to the source file `untitled.c` and call make, it will systematically check the recipes, top-down (in terms of project->objects->sources, not position in the file) and see by comparing the timestamps that `untitled.o` is older than its dependency and requires rebuilding.

Say you have the following, where you don't have a linear build recipe:

```
all: untitled

untitled: main.o a.o b.o c.o

main.o: main.c

a.o: a.c

b.o: b.c

c.o: c.c
```

The build system still works fine. Say you have functions in b which are used in both `main` and `a`. Once you've declared all of your functions in `b.h`, all you have to do is include that header in both main and a, and the functions will work as normal, even though main and a have no idea if the implementation in `b.c` has changed because they only have access to `b.h`.

Remember that a function name is essentially a pointer to it's location in memory. When you include another source file's header, you're essentially declaring the function prototypes, since the preprocessor is copying the header file's text into the file including it, as dictated by the specified directives. (This is equivalent to simply writing `extern void DoSomething();` or whatever the function's name and signature are.) You're not *defining* the functions, you're simply specifying that those functions have external linkage -thus the term, `extern`- and they will be mapped out by the linker later.

Once all the object files have been built, the linker uses the symbol table and relocation entries to generate a single executable file.

This is why a build system like make works. Since each compilation unit needs to know only the *structure* of a function in order to be able to call it (the parameters to the function must be placed on specific registers and/or the stack, depending on the ABI, platform, etc.), and not the implementation, any changes to another compilation unit should trigger only a recompilation of that unit and a call to the linker to re-map the executable.

To reiterate, the detection of the actual changes to the source file upon which an object file depends is handled by make by comparing the timestamps of the files. This means that you can artificially trigger a rebuild without modifying any dependencies by simply using the `touch` command on a source file and re-running make.

Hope this helps.